# How can I make some components in one tab (in a browser) work asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am developing a website which should display some graphs.
each graph gets data asynchronously to the others. i.e each graph gets data in other time independently to the others.
In my code I have some divs and each graph is displayed in a div(by connecting the divs to the highchart.js library that produces graphs).
How can I make the divs (the graphs in them) work  asynchronous to the other divs?? or you have another solution without divs??
thank you..

Comment: What do you mean by `'each graph gets data asynchronously to the others'` and `'work asynchronous to the other divs'`? I do not understand what it is you're asking.

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo ?

Comment: first, I developed a real time system in C++ that contains a count of threads that process some data. each thread provides data independently. In my asp.net project I need to display graphs that get their data by the threads. each graph represents data that processed by its own thread. my question is how can I make a connection between each graph in asp.net project  and the suitable thread in the C++ project when all the graphs are displayed in one common tab??? hope I clearified myself..

Comment: Unfortunately Im not asp.net / c++ developer so Im afraid that I cannot help with that